# Grouped bar graphs in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
|Good|Fair|Poor|Year|
|----|----|----|----|
| 50 | 20 | 52 |2001|
| 40 | 39 | 43 |2002|
| 60 | 65 | 59 |2003|
| 70 | 30 | 72 |2004|
| 76 | 80 | 74 |2005|
```

Each of the rows represents the percentage of products that passed a safety test
i.e. row 1 = 2005 -> in 2005 50% were good, 20% were fair, 52% were poor etc

I am trying to create a bar plot where the x-axis categories are the years and the bars in each category are sub-categorised into good, fair and poor; Preferably stacked instead of having the bars beside them.

I tried

```
library(ggpubr)
theme_set(theme_pubclean())
ggbarplot((top_offences_matrix), x = "YEARS", y = "NUMBER OF OFFENDERS",
          color = "color", fill = "color",
          palette = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"),
          label = FALSE,
          ggtheme = theme_pubclean()
)
```

but i'm getting this error message

```
Error in data[, x] : no 'dimnames' attribute for array
```

Any help on how to go about it?

Comment: Coul you please enter the output of `dput(YOUR_DATA_NAME)`?

Comment: And there are no years in your data frame, at least not the one you put there. So how can they be your x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, this works:

```
data %>%
  mutate(year = seq(1, nrow(.))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -year, names_to = "Quality type", values_to = "Percentage") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = Percentage, fill = `Quality type`))+
  geom_col()+
  theme_classic()
```

However, I had to create an `year` column, since your data didn't have it. Also, I made this using `ggplot2`, `dplyr` and `tidyr`, all of which are included in `tidyverse`.

Basically, what I did was turn the quality types into a single variable/column instead of having them separate, and then plotted that. `ggplot` likes everything in the long format.